# Unable to use [command] --help or -h to get help about a command in Mac OS terminal

Tags: macos, shell, command-line

From what I've read, `[command] -h` or `[command --help` can be used to get help about a command in the shell, but on my Mac OS Big Sur 11.4, I keep getting errors/unexpected results:

```
lorax@Loras-MacBook-Pro ~ % pwd --help
pwd: bad option: -h
lorax@Loras-MacBook-Pro ~ % pwd -h
pwd: bad option: -h

lorax@Loras-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls --help
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-@ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1%] [file ...]
lorax@Loras-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls -h
Applications        Inbox           eclipse-workspace
Desktop         Library         nltk_data
Documents       Movies          venv
Downloads       Music           venvV
ENV         Pictures
G Drive         Public

lorax@Loras-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd --help
cd: no such file or directory: --help
lorax@Loras-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd -h
cd: no such file or directory: -h
```

Meanwhile, flags with similar functions such as `man [command]` (and every other command I've tried so far for that matter) seem to work fine.

I'm very new to the shell/command line, so any insight as to why this is happening/what I did wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The OS X userland utilities were lifted from FreeBSD decades ago, and don't support a lot of features you might be used to from GNU versions.

Answer (score 0):

`command` and `binary` are different. `pwd` and `cd` are builtin commands by your shell (`bash`, `zsh`, etc), while `ls` is a real binary in (by default is `/bin/ls`). you can check where a binary located with `which ls`. Usually, but not all, binaries have `--help` argument, but of course not buildint command.

i recommend you to use `man` for manual of *any* commands. for example: `man ls` `man pwd` `man which`

```
❯ which cd
cd: shell built-in command

~
❯ which pwd
pwd: shell built-in command

~
❯ which ls
ls: aliased to lsd

~
❯ which lsd
/opt/homebrew/bin/lsd
```